# HOw to calculate the throughput from a trace file

Tags: awk, grep, ns2

for this command

```
$ grep ^r lab3.tr | grep "2 6" -c | awk "{s+=$6}END{print s}"
```

I am getting this error

```
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near }
```

and what does "h" stand for in the following line of trace file

**h** 0.106 1 7 cbr 100 ------- 1 1.0 5.0 6 6

Comment: Your command is purely based on the format of your file, how do you expect us to understand the format of your file? :-)

Comment: »» **h** 0.106 1 7 cbr 100 .. «« : Line starts with **h** in a trace file .... is usually an "out.nam" trace http://nsnam.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/NS-2_Trace_Formats

Comment: Please read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Comment: Also please ask 1 question at a time (no "**and** what does h stand for").

Comment: @Vijay Patil : Please see the ns2 "throughput awk" overview https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GbaWW6S65yMcIcOE7zSLi0C-KibiN00A/view?usp=sharing : ~25 different throughput scripts ..... to fit the most trace formats. .... Package, ns2 analyzing scripts https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uuVmyH8QPe4SRz2g1dnpfCIMvP26pCDj/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

You are using soft quotes around your `awk`-code so the shell interprets `$6`. As this argument is either empty or an unusable value, you receive said error. Use hard quotes for `awk`-code instead.

Example:

```
 $echo 1 2 3 | awk "{print $1}"
 1 2 3
```

=> shell interprets `$1`, however it is empty and thus only `print` is executed and it outputs the whole record.

```
$echo 1 2 3 | awk '{print $1}'
1
```

=> `awk` interprets `$1` as field in record and thus it outputs the first field.

Comment: I've never heard them referred to as "soft" and "hard" quotes before - I kinda like it!